# How to figure out how many ROIs are saved the .roi-file?

Tags: envi

I have some .roi-data with stored regions of interest which I created several years ago.
Now I would like to figure out, how many ROIsfor each class are saved in that .roi file. 
Open the .roi in Envi was not successful neither with an editor.
Has anyone an idea how to figure out the number of ROIs in the file??

Comment: Can you elaborate, what "not successful" means here? Were you not able to open the file or was the information unclear?

Comment: Sorry. It was not able (or I was not able?) to open the file in ENVI. Wit the editor, I only saw strange symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own solution.
I converted the .roi-file in ENVI by using Vector - Convert ROI to DXF and imported it in ArcGIS or QGIS where I could transform them to a .shp and identify the number of ROIs and edit them.